# C# Property Named Event

Tags: c#, json

I am using Json serializer and need to bind to a property name called 'event' Of course event is a keyword in C#, so doing something such as `string event { get; set; }` is not allowed. Is there anyway to go about doing that? I can't change the name of the object coming back to me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you're using Json.NET, you can use the [`JsonProperty` attribute](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm), or the [`@` symbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), or with a [`ContractResolver`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ContractResolver.htm) (there's a built-in one that makes things camelCase, so a property name of `Event` would serialize to `event`).

```
[JsonProperty("event")]
public string Event { get; set; }


public string @event { get; set; }


public string Event { get; set; }

var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
```

Comment: +1 for the `JsonProperty` which avoids the need to muck about with `@`ing everything.  Of course, there'll always be one poor soul who has to write in VB, so `Event` is also off-limits for them and they have to write `[Event]` to get around that, and will therefore complain that you should have used a different word entirely.

Answer (score 14):

Use @ to use [keywords as identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
string @event { get; set; }
```

> The prefix "@" enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is
>   useful when interfacing with other programming languages.
>   [...]
>   An identifier with an @ prefix is called a verbatim identifier. Use of
>   the @ prefix for identifiers that are not keywords is permitted, but
>   strongly discouraged as a matter of style.