# Need to create public parameter named "event"

Tags: c#, json

I need to parse JSON array in my C# application. Format example of JSON is as follows:

```
{"time":1440827858965,"event":{
//other arrays
}
```

This is my code for parsing:

```
public class Response
{
    public MatchEvent event { get; set; } //error is here
}

public class MatchEvent
{ 

}
```

I can't create a parameter named "event", beacause it's a keyword.

How can I parse the array or create parameter named "event"?

Comment: Can you do without using the key word?

Comment: did you at least read the attached dupe post? just add @ before the name...

Comment: @user3081756 I can't change the incoming JSON format.

Comment: @Gusman. But how can I parse the array?

Comment: I don0't understand, just name it  public MatchEvent @event { get; set; }

Comment: This is not a duplicate of linked question, IT Captain is asking how to achieve the deserialization he needs not specifically using a keywork. The problem for him was that it is a keyword. @IT Captain: its a property or member, a parameter is in the signature of a method. Maybe change the title?

Comment: If you use Newtonsoft.Json (JSON.NET) to parse your JSON, you can just name your property whatever in the class and use the JsonProperty [serialization attribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) on it: `[JsonProperty("event")]`.

Comment: @Gusman thanks. That worked.

Comment: @deebo you are right. Actually I want to parse the array that has C# keyword name and Gusman's tip helped.

Comment: so @ event did it? Let me know as I didn't know that. I've used it for @ class but didn't know a serializer would honour it. @Gusman . I do think I should point out that @ event as a property name is contrary to most c# style guidelines but if that is what your team uses... team style trumps community convention.

Comment: It is, but I faced the same problem and when the REST API you are trying to access is not under your control is that or kill yourself XD

Comment: @deebo so far it is working for json deserialization.

Comment: Nice! @Gusman I learned something. By the keyword being the solution IT Caption went with, this does become a duplicate question though :) Lawyered!

Comment: @Gusman how to convert if json contains something like this: `{"1":{"c1":"customer1","c2":"customer2"},"2":{"c1":"customer1","c2":"customer2"}}`. How to get "1" and "2"?

Comment: Here is a decent answer to your original question as well as a hint to any other deserialization. There are plenty of deserialization Q&A on SO:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203549/c-sharp-property-named-event?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the c# coding guidelines:

```
public class Response
{
  public MatchEvent Event { get; set; }
}
```

Then if you are using Json.NET (used in newer MS frameworks) you can set the formatter.
For example in WebAPI:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase
- http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm

See this question: [How can I return camelCase JSON serialized by JSON.NET from ASP.NET MVC controller methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445730/how-can-i-return-camelcase-json-serialized-by-json-net-from-asp-net-mvc-controll)

Answer (score 0):

There are some common ways to read the Json data. You can use `Dictionary<object,object>` to read the data and then use `<key,value>` pair to get the data and hence parse the json data.